# Parse a file with internal json twitter4j data to plain text

Tags: java, json, twitter4j

I have a file containing the data ( as obtained from Twitter4J methods like twitter.showUser()) and each of the line looks like

```
UserJSONImpl{
id=182857317,
name='Inria',
screenName='Inria',
location='France',
description='Institutderechercheensciencesdu#numérique,
ducôtédesinventeurs#informatique#mathématiques#innovation[
    compteofficiel
]',
isContributorsEnabled=false,
profileImageUrl='',
profileImageUrlHttps='',
url='',
isProtected=false,
followersCount=10171,
status=StatusJSONImpl{
    createdAt=MonOct2118: 56: 17CEST2013,
    id=392333528358088704,
    text='RT@upmc: Y'a-t-ilunpilotedansl'avion?Colloquiumd'#informatiquedemainsoirà18havecGillesDowek@Inria',
    source='<ahref=""rel="nofollow">TweetDeck</a>',
    isTruncated=false,
    inReplyToStatusId=-1,
    inReplyToUserId=-1,
    isFavorited=false,
    inReplyToScreenName='null',
    geoLocation=null,
    place=null,
    retweetCount=3,
    isPossiblySensitive=false,
    contributorsIDs=[
        J@3cbd7173,
        retweetedStatus=null,
        userMentionEntities=[
            UserMentionEntityJSONImpl{
                name='UPMC-Paris',
                screenName='upmc',
                id=19063270
            },
            UserMentionEntityJSONImpl{
                name='Inria',
                screenName='Inria',
                id=182857317
            }
        ],
        urlEntities=[
            URLEntityJSONImpl{
                url='',
                expandedURL='',
                displayURL=''
            }
        ],
        hashtagEntities=[
            HashtagEntityJSONImpl{
                text='informatique'
            }
        ],
        mediaEntities=[

        ],
        currentUserRetweetId=-1,
        user=null
    },
    profileBackgroundColor='FFFFFF',
    profileTextColor='343434',
    profileLinkColor='AAAAAA',
    profileSidebarFillColor='BDBDBD',
    profileSidebarBorderColor='FFFFFF',
    profileUseBackgroundImage=true,
    showAllInlineMedia=false,
    friendsCount=1209,
    createdAt=WedAug2517: 30: 06CEST2010,
    favouritesCount=927,
    utcOffset=7200,
    timeZone='Paris',
    profileBackgroundImageUrl='',
    profileBackgroundImageUrlHttps='',
    profileBackgroundTiled=false,
    lang='fr',
    statusesCount=2783,
    isGeoEnabled=false,
    isVerified=false,
    translator=false,
    listedCount=544,
    isFollowRequestSent=false
}
```

I would like to **convert** this data format **to a plain text format** with all the fields.

Thank you for the help

Comment: This looks like a `toString` representation of the object, it would be better if you could write it in the format you need as you receive results. Although I guess that's not possible here as you've already amassed the data?

Comment: Yes it is not possible and also the size of the data is very huge. That is why I am looking for solutions to change it. For  now, I am parsing the string to get the JSON format. Any further suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several APIs around for JSON - processing. 
The new JSR-353 (part of JEE 7) could be useful to you , you could try http://www.jdom.org/
just to mention two.
Both mainly iterate over the complete JSON - Object which can be constructed from a JSON - String.
So how to want to format your text? 
If you just want to put everything into a text - file you could append to a String member of your Main - class, 
if you want to produce a csv -text -file
you are translating between two different views of a data model 
and should build a proper data model for the csv - file before creating the view of it, the actual csv - file.

Comment: I indeed had a look at the JSON APIs but as far as I understand, it is not the JSON format. It is a twitter4J dump (entities as called in twitter4J - UserJSONImpl ). I want to convert it to, first a proper Json format and then parse the json file to read from its objects recursively.

Comment: Pardon me. Yes , you are right, this is not valid JSON. Well, this kind of transformations usually are done by regex, though it isn't too easy. You will need both a parser for the Twitter - Format which can read the string and then convert it, wherever it may be directly to your text format or to JSON. Take e.g. the isTruncated=false, so JSON would be isTruncated : false, but you can't simply substitute '=' for ':' , because the equals - sign could be part of a literal text, though I don't understand why Twitter4J doesn't use JSON.